# Xamarin ListView and ObservableCollection to show max 5 data

Tags: c#, xamarin

I need advice how can i do this, here is what my code look and from what i have to make that or to use different collection.

This is my DataModel

```
public class DataModel
{
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
}
```

and here is my DummyData in MainPage

```
public ObservableCollection<TransactionModel> dummyList{ get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<TransactionModel>();
public ObservableCollection<TransactionModel> DummyList{ get { return dummyList; } }

public void DummyData()
        {
            string dt = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy");


            dummyList.Add(new TransactionModel { Name= "1", TransactionDate = "03.11.2020", Value = "1" });
            dummyList.Add(new TransactionModel { Name= "2", TransactionDate = "25.10.2020", Value = "2" });
            dummyList.Add(new TransactionModel { Name= "3", TransactionDate = "25.9.2020", Value = "3" });
            dummyList.Add(new TransactionModel { Name= "4", TransactionDate = dt, Value = "4" });
            dummyList.Add(new TransactionModel { Name= "5", TransactionDate = dt, Value = "5" });
            dummyList.Add(new TransactionModel { Name= "6", TransactionDate = dt, Value = "6" });
            
            
            transactionView.ItemsSource = dummyList;
```

Comment: Why not create 2 ObservableCollections and have them contain the correct data for their specific listview?

Comment: Ideal would be to use 1, and use it in my MainPage and in my AllCollectionPage, how can i use it like this. In MainPage from ObservableCollections show only last 5 added, and in AllCollectionPage to show all from ObservableCollections.

Comment: Why would that be ideal? Common practice is that each Page has it's own ViewModel, specifically created to support that view and profide the data it needs (so I think many might not consider what you want an ideal solution). That said the problem is that the `ListView` directly subscribes to the `OnCollectionChanged` event of the `ObservableCollection` and adjusts it's content accordingly. Without either writing your own `IObservableCollection` implementation (or your own `ListView`) that supports what you want I don't think this can be done.

Comment: Well ideal for my question to do, i need to show same ObservableCollection (or the same data) in both classes MainPage where i want to restrict to 5 members(ListView) latest added.And in AllCollectionPage i would need to show all the Transactions i added in that ObservableCollection.  It's kinda bank app. And on MainPage i'm supposed to show max 5 members in ListView (so i think last 5 added would be great), and in AllCollectionPage where i will show all from the ObservableCollection as Transactions. Thanks hope you can understand me

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to create two different List , you could set a property to bind the **IsVisible** of the ViewCell . In this way you could set if let the specific item display .

#### in TransactionModel

```
public class TransactionModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    bool isVisible;

    public bool IsVisible
    {
        get
        {
            return isVisible;
        }
        set
        {
            if(isVisible!=value)
            {
                isVisible = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("IsVisible");
            }
        }
    }

    // other propertries
    //Description 
}
```

#### in Xaml

```
  <ListView  //...>

        <ListView.ItemTemplate>

            <DataTemplate>

                <StackLayout IsVisible="{Binding IsVisible}" >
                    
                    // Here I used StackLayout  just for demo , you could use Grid, Frame and so on
                    //...
                    
                </StackLayout>

            </DataTemplate>

        </ListView.ItemTemplate>

    </ListView>
```

#### In ViewModel

```
// if you want to display the item
obsList.Add(new TransactionModel{IsVisible = true, Description = "...", TransactionDate = "03.11.2020", Value = "..." });

// If you want to hide it
obsList.Add(new TransactionModel{IsVisible = false, Description = "...", TransactionDate = "03.11.2020", Value = "..." });
```

Comment: I only need to show data like DummyData, it's a practice task, and i got stack with filling my ListView in my MainPage. Where add 7 members to ObservableCollection, and i want to show only latest 5 members. But then also i need that same data (whole collection) so i can show in my other class where i will show in ListView all the members from ObservableCollection. So i don't change data or anything, just if u add more members that it's shows latest 5.

Comment: You could set the value of IsVisible as you need , my code is just for demo .

Comment: Yeah i understand it's not good my idea, but i'm first time trying this, is there any better way, for me to create in MainPage List<> or ObservableCollection<>, i manage to show in MainPage my data from ObservableCollection. But i don't understand how can i restrict it to only  latest 5 in ListView.

Comment: If you don't want to create two ObservableCollections , you need to use my solution .

Comment: Yeah buy in TransactionModel i have model data (date, value, name etec). So should i create new class?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225411/discussion-between-lucas-zhang-msft-and-gotstuckatm).